# jQuery validation does not validate my textarea element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am currently using jQuery validation to validate my fields. I've two fields, 
named "**comments**" & "**account name**". Both fields have the same rule method where **required is true**. When I click the "save" button, only the account name was validated. Why is that so? Here is a screenshot of my problem and my codes

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');

    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error')
        .addClass('has-success');
    },
  });

  $('#dataForm').validate({
    rules: {
      commentInput: {
        required: true
      },
      accountNameInput: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('success');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="commentInput">Comments</label>
    <textarea class="commentInput" id="commentInput" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
    <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput" placeholder="Account name" class="form-control font-bold" value="" />
  </div>


  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give all form fields that need validation a `name` attribute. That's where the validation plugin gets the reference to the element from.

From the **[documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)**:

> Throughout the documentation, two terms are used very often, so it's
>   important that you know their meaning in the context of the validation
>   plugin:
>
> **method**: A validation method implements the logic to validate an element, like an email method that checks for the right format of a
>   text input's value. A set of standard methods is available, and it is
>   easy to write your own.
>
> **rule**: A validation rule associates an element with a validation method, like "validate input with ***name*** "primary-mail" with
>   methods "required" and "email".

The `name` attribute is also required to be present on any form field that will need to transmit its data as part of the form submission.

```js
$(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error')
        .addClass('has-success');
    },
  });

  $('#dataForm').validate({
    rules: {
      commentInput: {
        required: true
      },
      accountNameInput: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('success');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="commentInput">Comments</label>
    <textarea class="commentInput" id="commentInput" name="commentInput" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
    <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput" placeholder="Account name" class="form-control font-bold" value="" />
  </div>


  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

The validation plugin targets by the name attribute:

`<textarea id="commentInput" name="commentInput" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>`

Comment: In the time I worked it out the answer had been posted Scoot.

Answer (score -1):

You need use the name attribute for validate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorClass: 'help-block',
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .addClass('has-error');

    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element)
        .closest('.form-group')
        .removeClass('has-error')
        .addClass('has-success');
    },
  });

  $('#dataForm').validate({
    rules: {
      commentInput: {
        required: true
      },
      accountNameInput: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      alert('success');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form id="dataForm" method="post" action="#">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="commentInput">Comments</label>
    <textarea name="commentInput" class="commentInput" id="commentInput" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="accountNameInput">Account name</label>
    <input type="text" id="accountNameInput" name="accountNameInput" placeholder="Account name" class="form-control font-bold" value="" />
  </div>


  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="saveButton" />

</form>
```

Comment: Use name attribute for validate

Comment: While I was responding, new answers have been added. I started answering more than three minutes ago.